# Shiny -- display the options of a select input in a specific (non-alphabetic) order

Tags: r, string, shiny

I am trying to populate the dropdown menu of a selectInput with unique values in a column in the file that the user will upload. But the problem is that I would like to display the choices in a certain non-alphabetic order, so I can't just use

```
updateSelectInput(....., choices = sort(unique(dataframe$column)))
```

The four possible options are: economy, premium economy, business, and first. I would like to display them in such order whenever they are present in the dataframe .

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Not sure, but you coud try `factor(c("economy", "premium economy", "business", "first"), levels = c("economy", "premium economy", "business", "first"))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried `choices = factor(unique(dataframe$Column), levels = c("Economy", "Premium economy", "Business", "First"), ordered = TRUE`, In the dropdown menu, however,  it only displays the indices of the levels that are present in the column.

Comment: set the factor level on the `data.frame$Column`, then in the dropdown use `choices = as.character(dataframe$Column)`

Comment: @Symbolix Hi. Thanks for the answer. I tried your method and created a factor called `cabin` with the four levels.  But I still got them in the same order as they appear in the dataset, and I also got NAs for the levels that are not present. I fixed the issue by using `choices = levels(factor(cabin))` instead of `as.character`. But thank you anyways for the tip on using factors. Don't know why that didn't occur to me earlier.

Comment: glad I could help. If you've answered your own question you should add it as an answer, and then accept/tick your answer (after the 2 day limit), so that others know it has been solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed the problem with hints from @Symbolix. I first created a factor:

```
cabin <- factor(dataframe$column, levels = c("Economy", "Premium Econ",  "Business", "First"))
```

In the `updateSelectInput`, I have

```
...., choices = levels(factor(cabin))
```

Calling `factor` again removes the NAs that are generated for the levels not present in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If the set of 4 options you mentioned can be hard coded into your app, then you can use `intersect` to accomplish this.  Let's say you put the contents of the file the user uploaded into a data.frame called `d1`, and the column of interest is `Class`.  Get the set of options by intersecting the full set of options with the set of unique levels in the data.

## ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("SelectInput using ordered unique choices from a column"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(fileInput(inputId = "SampleFile", label = "Upload a csv")),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("Drop1"),
      uiOutput("Drop2"),
      textOutput(outputId = "outCLASS1"),
      textOutput(outputId = "outCLASS2")
    )
  )
))
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

  d1 = reactive({
    if(is.null(input$SampleFile)){return(NULL)
    } else {d1 = read.csv(input$SampleFile$datapath)
    return(d1)} })

  AllOptions = c("economy", "premium economy", "business", "first")

  OptionSet1 = reactive({intersect(AllOptions, levels(d1()$Class)) })
  output$Drop1 = renderUI({ selectizeInput(inputId = "CLASS1", label = "Pick a class", choices = OptionSet1())})

  OptionSet2 = reactive({intersect(AllOptions, levels(d1()$Category2)) })
  output$Drop2 = renderUI({ selectizeInput(inputId = "CLASS2", label = "Pick a class", choices = OptionSet2())})

  output$outCLASS1 = reactive({input$CLASS1})
  output$outCLASS2 = reactive({input$CLASS2})

})
```